# [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword() - Type Not found

Tags: powershell, class, passwords

Why do I get Type Not Found when trying to use this class/method in PowerShell?

```
 [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword()
```

Do I need to install a module or something to make use of it?

Comment: Haha i should've known. Forgot about having to add it first. Long day! Thanks.

Comment: What version of .NET and PowerShell are using?  I see this on 5.1 in both Win7 and Win10.  Additionally, `GeneratePassword` requires two arguments.

Comment: 5.1.17134.228 , .net 4.7.03056 i think

Comment: Did you remove the Add-type comment answer? Please put it back since it can be useful.

Comment: It did not apply to this question and was misleading since that type should be loaded as a default on PowerShell v5.1 so I removed it.

Comment: Strange, i really had to do add-type -AssemblyName System.Web

Comment: Hm, maybe I have it imported on my profile somewhere..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Load the assembly first:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,0)
```

Answer (score 26):

For those landing here who are using PowerShell Core, as per this link:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5352

> .NET Core does not support System.Web.dll

As such `[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword()` will result in the same `Type Not Found` error in PowerShell Core even with the `add-type` fix above.

You'll have to roll your own password generator.

Comment: Sad that there is no inbuilt alternative. I'm using `$pass = ([char[]]([char]33..[char]95) + ([char[]]([char]97..[char]126)) + 0..9 | sort {Get-Random})[0..12] -join ''` per [this blog][1]


  [1]: https://www.undocumented-features.com/2016/09/20/powershell-random-password-generator/

Comment: Here's a nice blog post on how to do it:
https://dev.to/onlyann/user-password-generation-in-powershell-core-1g91

Comment: This answer is not entirely accurate.  Using PowerShell 5.1 will work, but using 6+ will not.

Comment: @RashadRivera Well, yes, but this particular answer relates specifically to PowerShell __Core__ and is accurate for that version. Versions 1.0 through 5.1 of PowerShell are known as Windows PowerShell. Version 6.0 is known as PowerShell Core. Versions 7+ are known as PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to roll your own.  You only need to understand how PowerShell is behaving in version 6+.

I'm running PowerShell 7 and when I try to use the techniques described here, I get the same *Membership type is not found* error.

When using PowerShell 5.1, I confirmed that before using the `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web`, the Membership type was not found.  After using it, it works.

Going forward, you will need to find a different solution for PowerShell versions 6+.  But so long as you have 5, you should be able to add the System.Web assembly to access Membership class.